# Batch Script - Pull values from text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, text, time

I have a folder with thousands of sub-folders, each containing one video file, and one subtitle file, like this:

[image: screenshot of Windows explorer view]

Each of those text files (.srt) are subtitle files intended to display the filename (without extension) at the beginning and end of each video. For example, the contents of Track Two - Track Two.srt are:

```
1
00:00:00,500 --> 00:00:03,500
Track Two - Track Two

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Track Two - Track Two
```

Thanks to some serious StackHeads, I've been able to automate the creation of the text files by running the following batch script in the ./media/ parent directory:

```
for /R %%f in (*.flv *.mp4) do (
echo(1
echo(00:00:00,500 --^> 00:00:03,500
echo(%%~nf
echo(
echo(2
echo(00:00:00,000 --^> 00:00:00,000
echo(%%~nf
) > "%%~dpnf.srt"
```

Now all I have left to do is update the sixth line of each .srt file to make it show the filename for three seconds just prior to the end of the video. Ideally, the first numerical value would be 3.5 seconds prior to the end of the video, and the second value would be .5 seconds prior to the end.. and to make it even harder, it has to be in the Russian timecode .srt files use.

For example, if Track Two - Track Two is 01:36 long, the 6th line of Track Two - Track Two.srt should read:

```
00:01:32,500 --> 00:01:35,500
```

I can generate a text list of all of the video lengths, like this:

[image]

..and as long as I keep the folder names strictly numbered, they'll line up every time.

Is there any way to pull out the video lengths from the text file times.txt (assuming the order is perfect), and update the 6th line of each .srt file in Russian timecode format to make it display the title prior to the end the video file it references?

Any help is graciously appreciated!!
Also.. thanks again to dbenham, MC ND, payeli for your help before!! You're the best!

Comment: Would be very useful to know whether you can individually calculate the length of `Track Two - Track Two` or whether you could produce your textfile of lines like `0:04:56 Track Two - Track Two`

Comment: I can do even better--  here is the full .csv file showing all data available: http://sendspace.com/file/33czf3 (list.csv) - I use a program called PlayTime to generate the .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=2,3,11delims=," %%a IN (list.csv) DO (
 SET ttrack=%%a
 SET videoname=%%~nb
 set to_file="%%c\%%~nb.srt"
 CALL :process
)
GOTO :EOF
:process
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=:" %%r IN ("%ttrack%") DO (
 SET /a hr=10%%r
 SET /a mi=1%%s
 SET /a se=1%%t
)
CALL :subs 1
SET endtime=%hr:~-2%:%mi:~-2%:%se:~-2%,500
CALL :subs 3
SET starttime=%hr:~-2%:%mi:~-2%:%se:~-2%,500

echo(1
echo(00:00:00,500 --^> 00:00:03,500
echo(!videoname!
echo(
echo(2
echo(%starttime% --^> %endtime%
echo(!videoname!
ECHO(sent to %to_file%
GOTO :eof
::
:: subtract %1 seconds from hr,mi,se
::
:subs
SET /a se-=%1
IF %se% geq 100 GOTO :EOF
SET /a se+=60
SET /a mi-=1
IF %mi% geq 100 GOTO :EOF
SET /a mi+=60
SET /a hr-=1
GOTO :eof
```

Not hard.

All you'd need to do if this seems appropriate is to change

```dos
echo(1
...
echo(%videoname%
ECHO(sent to %to_file%
```

to

```dos
(
echo(1
...
echo(%videoname%
)>%to_file%
```

Comment: You sir have some serious talent.. I'm going to rush home from work and try this asap, I'll report back.... I can't thank you enough

Comment: OKAY-- This got me 99% there!! a few small issues came up though.. All the .srt files are being created in the parent folder, and not the subfolders where the videos are. Also, I changed 'set to_file="%%~dpnc.srt"' to ..."%%~nb.srt" to make the .srt files match the file names and not the numbered subdirectories. I even tried ..."%%~dpnb.srt" thinking that would create the .srt files in the subfolders, but no luck. Lastly.. it's not handling special characters very well and is breaking operation when it hits characters like ° or & .. any ideas??  Thanks for all the help!!!!

Comment: Altered a tad. Echo `!videoname!` to get over the `&` problem and `%%~dpc%%~nb.srt` should grab the directory/path from `%%c` but the filename from `%%b`

Comment: !videoname! works great.. but even with %%~dpc%%~nb.srt its still dumping into the parent dir..  any thoughts?  Thanks again!!

Comment: Ah - so the destinationfile should be `"C:\media\0002  Track Two & Track Two\Track Two & Track Two.srt"` (where I replaced `-` with `&` for testing...) ? If so, fixed. If not, please exemplify required `.srt` filename.

Comment: YOU'VE DONE IT!! "%%c\%%~nb.srt" worked PERFECTLY! You've saved me DAYS, DAYS of manually entering the info! May you live for a thousand years.

Comment: Hey Magoo! I just want to thank you again for all your help! I learned a lot from our brief interaction, and even modified the code further to use cells from the csv file as the videos title within the subtitle files! Now all I have to do is make the titles look right in the csv and run the batch process! For some reason, it never clicked for me until you took the time. If I ever find myself Down Under.. I owe you a lager my friend. Thanks again.